# Buscar arquivo em várias pasta a partir de uma pasta base, exceto a pasta

Tags: c#

```
string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Teste_Zip\web", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

A pergunta é:
Preciso pegar os arquivos, exceto em uma pasta. Não consegui excetuar a pasta. A pasta tem nome Fixo, não varia.

Fiz isso e diz que não é possível converte char em string[]. A var arquivos é um array de string.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(arquivos.ToString());

        }
```

Tudo que preciso é trazer o nome dos arquivos e sem o path dos arquivos.

Desta forma aqui, resolveu:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = string.Empty;
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();

            string path = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Caminho_Base"];

            string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach(var item in arquivos)
            {
                s = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
                if (!item.Contains("TSNMVC"))
                    lista.Add(s);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma condição usando LINQ

```
var arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Teste_Zip\web", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(x => x.StartsWith("Nome da pasta a excluir")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Não funcionou, porque `arquivos` no meu contexto é arquivos e preciso eliminar as pastas.

Comment: Verdade. Tente usando `StartsWith()`, deve produzir o efeito esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas ajustando o código do jbueno acredito funcionar para o que você precisa.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Teste_Zip\web", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(d => !d.Contains("C:\Teste_Zip\PASTA_A_EXCLUIR")).ToArray();
```